# How to prevent function to fire multiple times when triggered

Tags: javascript

I am trying to track video progress and send events based on the video current time percentage. However I am having issue when the video is long, for example getPercentage is returning `10` multiple of times on the video because it is rounding up 10.n multiple times. How can I only make the logs to trigger once?

```js
function getPercentage(a, b) {
    return ((a/b)*100)
}
setInterval(() => {
    const progress = Number(getPercentage(currentTime, durationTotal).toFixed(0));
  
  switch(progress) {
    case 10:
        console.log('test 10')
    break;
    case 25:
        console.log('test 25')
    }
}, 1000)
```

I am expecting that what it is in switch case should trigger only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the already fired events in an array and check if a value already is in that array. If true, don't log.

```
var already_sent = [];

if (already_sent.includes(progress) == false){
    already_sent.push(progress);
    console.log(progress);
}
```

Or if you only want specific percentages to be logged, have an array containing those values and remove when matched:

```
var log_perc = [10, 25, 50, 75];
if (log_perc.includes(progress) == true){
    log_perc.remove(progress);
    console.log(progress);
}
```

Comment: Using an object would be more efficient here. I don't see any need to track the sequence the events appear in.

Comment: @Quentin how would you set up the object? like  `{ 10: true, 25: true ..}` ?

Comment: @kakad — yes. It doesn't need anything more complex.